# defining Custom Id in JPA

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am new to spring JPA. My Requirement is to have an ID of composite columns. I have a ledger table where I have two columns log_id and order_id. I have to insert the multiple record for the same order_id but I want log_id should get increment every time only when the same order_id is coming.

Like:

```
order_id        log_id
--------         -----
1234              1
1234              2
1234              3
1235              1
```

is it possible in spring JPA. Can anyone help?
Thanks in advance!!!!

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using @IdClass and @GeneratedValue.

Code Sample:

```
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.IdClass;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="LEDGER")
@IdClass( PK.class )
public class Ledger {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "log_id")
    @GeneratedValue
    public int logId;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "order_id")
    public int orderId;

    public String otherFields;
}
```

Id class

```
import java.io.Serializable;

public class PK implements Serializable{
    public int logId;
    public int orderId;

    public PK() {

    }

    public PK(int logId, int orderId) {
        super();
        this.logId = logId;
        this.orderId = orderId;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + logId;
        result = prime * result + orderId;
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        PK other = (PK) obj;
        if (logId != other.logId)
            return false;
        if (orderId != other.orderId)
            return false;
        return true;
    }

}
```

For further reading follow below links

1. [IdClass](https://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/entity/id#Composite_Primary_Key_)
2. [GeneratedValue](https://www.objectdb.com/api/java/jpa/GeneratedValue)
3. [Examples](https://vladmihalcea.com/how-to-map-a-composite-identifier-using-an-automatically-generatedvalue-with-jpa-and-hibernate/)

Comment: How log_id column value are getting incremented here?

Comment: it is like having auto-increment sequence...you can have your own custom sequence defined in your database and use that sequence for generating next order_id... https://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/entity/generated

Comment: I am getting following error while persisting the entity "Could not set field value [POST_INSERT_INDICATOR] value by reflection"

Comment: I am using the GeneratedType.Identity in the above suggested identity class

Comment: Have you generated getter-setter for all properties in Ledger class and also in PK class

Comment: Can you copy paste stacktrace here